# Machine Learning for choosing the right cover box to contain smaller item boxes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, predictive-models, data-mining

I am studying on choosing the right box to contain item boxes.

When customers order items, items have their own cases and ordered items are packed with the right cover box to contain them to deliver. I want to use Machine Learning to choose the right cover box.

I am trying to find a way to apply Machine Learning to choose the right cover box to pack items but days spent and I cannot find the starting point to start off for the task with Machine Learning to build a model.

I have gone through bin packing and knapsack theories and I sort of understand them. However, I want to use Machine Learning but having trouble to get start off.

There are 10 different types of cover boxes. The cover box can contain multiple items and it is a rectangle shape. All items are also contained in their own rectangle boxes. Of course, the cover box has to be bigger than an item box or item boxes if multiple items are chosen to be packed.

The variables of a cover box and an item box are the same and they are as follows:

- Height
- Width
- Depth
- Weight it can hold

For the first time, as there are 10 different types of cover boxes, any item or items ordered must be contained in a cover box, so I thought it is a classification problem but in some I wonder if I can do it using clustering.

Should I think of it as classification or clustering? Hope to hear some explanations.

Comment: It's cheaper to do it without machine learning

Comment: This is a variant of the NP-hard "bin packing problem". There is no efficient optimal algorithm for an arbitrary number of items, but there are many heuristic approaches. In practice, a brute force method for finding the optimal solution could be feasible for a small number of items.